# How can I add a closet to an existing room?

Tags: design, bedroom, renovation

So I am looking to add a closet to an existing room. I want this to be a built-in because where I live real estate listings do not count a bedroom with a free standing closet. However I can't ever recall seeing someone's house with this and I can't help but think it will look terrible. Is it possible to have a closet that builds out into the room, but still looks nice? I was thinking of placing it where the 19" short wall is and covering up an existing door.

[image]

Comment: 2 possible places the one you mentioned and bottom right corner at the 37" wall, this last one will give a little corridor effect on coming in

Comment: @ratchetfreak - thanks, that is a very good idea. I hadn't thought about the corridor effect. Now that I think about it, that does seem like a naturally better location.

Comment: If you show some more of the surrounding floor plan, we may be able to suggest some other alternatives as well. For example, it is sometimes possible to split an existing closet in an adjoining room into to. You say the one door can be removed -- where does it go? Can the inside of that room be turned into a closet?

Comment: @gregmac - thanks for the floorplan suggestion, unfortunately the surrounding area won't allow building out into another room. Along the left wall is a narrow hallway, 30", and along the bottom wall is a galley bathroom.

Comment: Nice work. I have the same problem - a kid's room that needs a closet. How deep and wide did you make it? I'm trying to make it as small as possible but still useable. Thanks for the picture.

Comment: @Lynn - We went with 2'x4' interior space. Turned the studs ninety degrees so that walls would be extra thin. Door is a 30" bifold from HD. Works very well. I'll post a picture of the inside with clothing later tonight so that you can see how the spacing works. In hindsight I wished that I had trimmed it 2" less deep. It couldn't get any narrower without encroaching on the trim.

Comment: @Lynn - added the picture to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So based on advice from ratchetfreak in comments I took his advice and went with the 'corridor' effect on the 37" wall (pic below). As the room has two doors it gave me an interesting perspective on what the 'walking into the room' vibe was. For door #1 (the bottom door in pic) I felt like the closet made the room feel smaller on entrance. For door #2 (left wall) I was really surprised that walking into the room didn't feel like the closet was overbearing.

So my end analysis is that a closet jutting into the room across from a doorway is fine. Also, that a corridor effect makes a room feel smaller on entrance. I prefer option one, although we ended up going with option two because it really was the only place the closet would fit.

[image]
[image]

Comment: nicely done (but don't forget the crown moulding!)

Comment: @DA01 - haha, I couldn't find crown moulding that matched! Maybe that's a new diy.se question

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Ikea closets. They are pretty functional and are designed to look built in.

Also I don't think there's any actual law requiring a closet in the bedroom. So you can call any room a bedroom as long as it has appropriate egress, door and your septic tank is big enough.

Comment: I saw a brand new house on the market that had to advertise that the builder would add a closet to the room before they could call it a bedroom. If it isn't a law, then maybe it is just an understanding among listing agents?

Comment: I've heard the reverse, if a room *has* a closet, it's considered a bedroom, and therefore must meet code requirements for bedrooms (egress, fire alarm, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In North Carolina, we were able to get the price of a house reduced about $10k because the listing said 4 bedrooms but one room had no built in closet, so it had to be sold as a 3 bedroom with a finished bonus room.